# Jquery to detect if duplicate values in forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have built a dynamic table containing form fields that can be added or removed when required.

What im wondering is.. Is there a plugin or script that has been created that can search a set of form fields for duplicate values ?

Example.

We have a form field with a class of "field-name"

this field may exist 10 times on the page because its part of dynamic rows.

So what im hoping is.. for a plugin that wont allow duplicate values to exist in these fields on the page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the fields yourself with a few lines of code. The below runs on form submit and creates a copy of the original values with duplicates removed. If the lists don't match then you know you have some duplicate values.

```
$('form').submit(function (evt) {
    var dynamicFields = $('.field-name'),
        uniques = $.unique(dynamicFields);
    if (uniques.length != dynamicFields.length) {
       alert('Please make sure all your values are unique.');
       return false;
    }
});
```